# How to test for the presence of a Link component with a specific href

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, chai, enzyme

I'm trying out some tests with `expect` and `enzyme`, and I'm trying to add some tests for a `<Header />` Component.

For the Header, I want to test that somewhere it contains a link to `/login`. Inside my header it's implemented like this:

`<Link className="nav-link" to="/login">Login</Link>`

Ideally, I would also set the state of the user to be logged in or not logged in and then test whether or not the `Link` renders a link to `/login` or a link to `/logout`.

I've been reading through the docs for `enzyme` and searching online but haven't found any tips on this. Any ideas?

Comment: oops, another bug

Comment: Well, interesting. I was thinking about searching for an anchor tag and checking its href but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Do not know will it be useful or not, but in parallel situation - when I wanted to test text of the button at multilanguage app, I added some class to className (without any corresponding css, just to mark state of component) and then check it at tests.

Comment: I guess your previous comment means this is some sort of common issue or bug within React testing?

Comment: No! I had two open tabs with different bugs, and i posted comment to wrong window, sorry